# how can I divide all raws by first raw and calculate standard deviation

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<-structure(list(R1 = c(512L, 44620L, 69500L, 91120L, 98870L), 
    R2 = c(587L, 38500L, 67370L, 94870L, 88120L), R3 = c(587L, 
    39370L, 57500L, 96870L, 85370L), R1.1 = c(737L, 2812L, 4050L, 
    6400L, 4762L), R2.1 = c(450L, 2587L, 3900L, 7287L, 5550L), 
    R3.1 = c(712L, 2175L, 4675L, 6687L, 4125L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I am trying to do the following

```
    R1    R2    R3 R1.1 R2.1 R3.1
1   512   587   587  737  450  712
2 44620 38500 39370 2812 2587 2175
3 69500 67370 57500 4050 3900 4675
4 91120 94870 96870 6400 7287 6687
5 98870 88120 85370 4762 5550 4125
```

I can calculate it like the following

```
((mean(c(512,587,587))-(mean(c(512,587,587))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(44620,38500,39370))-(mean(c(512,587,587))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(69500,67370,57500))-(mean(c(512,587,587))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(91120,94870,96870))-(mean(c(512,587,587))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(98870,88120,85370))-(mean(c(512,587,587))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(2812,2587,2175))-(mean(c(737,450,712))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(4050,3900,4675))-(mean(c(737,450,712))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(6400,7287,6687))-(mean(c(737,450,712))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
((mean(c(4762,5550,4125))-(mean(c(737,450,712))))- 1822.9)/4167.5
```

However, I want to do it in an easier way as well as add SD to each calculation as well

Let take the mean the second row for R1,R2 and R3 column
then minus the mean of the first row of those 3 column
then minus a constant value - 1822.9 and divide by another constant value 4167.5. I do the same for the third , fourth and fifth row
Then I do the same for the second set of column R1.1, R1.2 and R1.3

I can calculate the sd like this

```
(sd(c(512,587,587))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(44620,38500,39370))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(69500,67370,57500))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(91120,94870,96870))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(98870,88120,85370))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(2812,2587,2175))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(4050,3900,4675))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(4050,3900,4675))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd(c(6400,7287,6687))-1822.9)/4167.5
(sd((c(4762,5550,4125)))-1822.9)/4167.5
```

So the output without SD is like this

```
 data.       SD
-0.4374085  -0.43
9.224979    0.35
14.97423    1.09
22.05201    0.26
21.21218    1.27
0.0165007   -0.36
0.4204999   -0.34
1.040296    -0.32
0.5654309   -0.26
```

Comment: Can you explain in words how you want to scale your values? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how can I divide all raws by first raw and calculate standard deviation". What are these numbers (`1822.9`, `4167.5`) in your explicit example?

Comment: @Maurits Evers
 those values are constant , I explain it above

Comment: Ah, so the `R.1`, `R.2`, `R.3` columns are not your expected output? Can you include your expected output as a `data.frame` for the sample data you give?

Comment: @Maurits Evers
 of course it has, look at my R calculation that I did above, the output is there but I am trying to add the Standard deviation too

Comment: *"trying to add the Standard deviation too"* I don't know what that means. Add the SD how? What are you calculating? At the moment you've given us some code without much explanation and you're leaving it up to us to figure out *what* you're calculating. Like I said, I don't understand what you mean by "*how can I divide all raws by first raw and calculate standard deviation*". What's a "raw"?

Comment: @Maurits Evers
 Only return the sd of the first mean

Comment: There is no SD of a mean. The mean is a scalar.

Comment: @Maurits Evers
I wrote it above , I show how the output look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using vectorised base R functions where possible (avoiding explicit loops)

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(
    list(1:3, 4:6), 
    \(sel) data.frame(
        data = (rowMeans(df[sel]) - rowMeans(df[sel])[1] - 1822.9) / 4167.5,
        SD = (apply(df[sel], 1, sd) - 1822.9) / 4167.5)))
#         data         SD
#1  -0.4374085 -0.4270183
#2   9.2249790  0.3570573
#3  14.9742292  1.0988897
#4  22.0520136  0.2630226
#5  21.2121816  1.2744407
#6  -0.4374085 -0.3992622
#7   0.0165007 -0.3598939
#8   0.4204999 -0.3387773
#9   1.0402959 -0.3288037
#10  0.5654309 -0.2661231
```

The idea is to split the source `data.frame` `df` into two chunks (consisting of col1-3 and col4-6); then loop over those two chunks, calculate the quantities needed and row-bind them using `do.call(rbind, ...)`. Base R doesn't have a `rowSd()` function so we implement this through `apply(..., 1, sd)`; you can also use `matrixStats::rowSds()` if you don't mind an additional dependency (`matrixStats::rowSds()` will be more performant than the `apply(..., 1, sd)` solution).

---

Using `matrixStats::rowSds()`

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(
    list(1:3, 4:6), 
    \(sel) data.frame(
        data = (rowMeans(df[sel]) - rowMeans(df[sel])[1] - 1822.9) / 4167.5,
        SD = (rowSds(as.matrix(df[sel])) - 1822.9) / 4167.5)))
```

Comment: can you please change the sd too, I will accept your answer

Comment: Please see my edit @nik

Comment: look at my SD , they are different bro

Comment: Ah I see. Fixed.